# What is this MATLAB statement for: [M N ~] = size(imge);?

Tags: matlab

What does this statement mean???

```
[M N ~] = size(imge);
```

I don't understand the reason to use this "~", and this statement also gives an error message.

Comment: you need to use commas: `[M,N,~] = size(image);` (requires MATLAB R2009b or newer): http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/

Comment: @Amro: why do you say you need commas? On R2010b (WinXP) it works fine without commas. I suspect chee is using something pre-R2009b, so the tilde is not allowed at all...

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg: for some reason, I remember that when using the tilde to ignore outputs, you needed commas to separate the list of variables... Was this once required but changed in recent MATLAB versions, or is it just my imagination??

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg: In general, you should use commas when using `~` as Amro says. What you say is true _only for this specific case_ when `~` appears in the last position. If you don't use commas and it precedes a variable (for e.g., `[~ M N]`), its role there is that of the `not` operator and negates `M`. MATLAB will give you an error saying "LHS assignments cannot contain expressions"

Comment: @yoda: yes that's what I had in mind.. thank you for reminding me

Comment: Thanks @yoda :-)... always good to learn things while one answers questions ;-).

Comment: my questions are not being posted here ,i dont know why???? :o

Comment: it gives the error "•It does not meet our quality standards." for any type of question? whats wrong :((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MATLAB versions since 2009b, you can use the tilde (`~`) [to ignore outputs which you don't need](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-1.html#br67dkp-1). If it gives you an error, that means your version doesn't support this use of the tilde and you have to replace it with a dummy variable name as so:

```
[M N dummy] = size(imge);
```

As Sumona explains, M will contain the number or rows in the image and N the number of columns; dummy will be 1 (for one black-and-white image), 3 (for one colour image) or an arbitrary integer (for an image stack).

Usually it only makes sense to use the tilde if there are other parameters you are interested afterwards. `size` is an exception here in that it checks (using `nargout`) how many outputs it should produce and changes its behavior accordingly, [as documented here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/size.html).

That is,

```
test = zeros(3,4,5);
[M N dummy] = size(test);
```

produces M=3,N=4 as one would expect, but

```
test = zeros(3,4,5);
[M N] = size(test);
```

produces M=3,N=20.

In your particular case, I assume `imge` is an image stack and the programmer wanted to find out the size of the individual images, but not how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

`[M N D]=size(img)`;

**size** command would give you the number of rows in the first variable M,the number of columns in the second variable N and the number of dimensions in the third variable D for the parameter image in this case. If it is a gray scaled image then D=2 and if it is a RGB image then D=3. If your statement gives error,then it is wise to stick to the normal convention as I have shown you. Hope this helps :)