# What does this function definition SomeFunction(hObject,~) mean in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I guess this is something from new version of Matlab. But I can't figure out what does `~` represent.

```
SomeFundtion(hObject,~)
%function content here
```

Any clue would be appreciated.

In addition, maybe it's me but I can't always find a good resource to find this kind of special operator in matlab. Any recommendation of good resource for matlab?

Comment: The resource depends on your needs I think. YAGTOM (http://code.google.com/p/yagtom/) was a nice free reference to read for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used to ignore function inputs. Related [MATLAB reference page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br67dkp-1.html) tells:

> Use this operator when your function must accept a predefined set of
>   inputs, but your function does not use all of the inputs. Common
>   applications include defining callback functions, as shown here, or
>   deriving a class from a superclass.

You may refer to the reference for example code.

Tilde is also used for ignoring some outputs. You may refer to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766330/what-is-this-matlab-statement-for-m-n-sizeimge) for that kind of usage.

Comment: Hi, are you able to reproduce some of the examples from the linked page, as the linked page is not found now.